# dynatree js showing tree expanded initially

Tags: javascript, tree, salesforce, visualforce

I have created a js tree with dynatree.js. I have a very long hierarchy. the tree is showing expanded on load. i want the tree should expand up to one level. Below is my code

```
<apex:component controller="TreeViewController">
    <apex:attribute name="roleOrUserId" required="true" type="String" assignTo="{!roleOrUserId}" description="Enter Role or User Id to build the hierarchy. Pass null if you are passing JSON data as a parameter" />
    <apex:attribute name="selectable" type="Boolean" assignTo="{!selectable}" description="Do you want nodes to be selectable?" />
    <apex:attribute name="value" type="String" description="IDs of selected Nodes in CSV format" />
    <apex:attribute name="JsonData" type="String" assignTo="{!JsonData}" description="JSON input for the tree component" />
    <apex:inputHidden id="selectedKeys" value="{!value}" />
    <!--<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.DynaTree, 'jquery/jquery.js' )}" /> -->
    <apex:includescript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.DynaTree, 'jquery/jquery-ui.custom.js' )}" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.DynaTree, 'jquery/jquery.cookie.js' )}" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.DynaTree, 'src/jquery.dynatree.js' )}" />
    <!--<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.DynaTreeJs}" /> -->

    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.DynaTree, 'src/skin/ui.dynatree.css')}" />

    <!-- Add code to initialize the tree when the document is loaded: -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function(){
            // Attach the dynatree widget to an existing <div id="tree"> element
            // and pass the tree options as an argument to the dynatree() function:
            $("#tree").dynatree({
                onActivate: function(node) {
                    // A DynaTreeNode object is passed to the activation handler
                    // Note: we also get this event, if persistence is on, and the page is reloaded.
                    //alert("You activated " + node.data.key);
                },
                persist: false,
                checkbox: true,
                generateIds: false,
                classNames: {
                    checkbox: "dynatree-checkbox",
                    expanded: "dynatree-expanded"
                },
                selectMode: 3,
                children: {!JsonString},
                onSelect: function(select, node) {
                    // Get a list of all selected nodes, and convert to a key array:
                    var selKeys = $.map(node.tree.getSelectedNodes(), function(node){
                        return node.data.key;
                    });
                    jQuery(document.getElementById("{!$Component.selectedKeys}")).val(selKeys.join(", "));

                    // Get a list of all selected TOP nodes
                    var selRootNodes = node.tree.getSelectedNodes(true);
                    // ... and convert to a key array:
                    var selRootKeys = $.map(selRootNodes, function(node){
                        return node.data.key;
                    });
                },

            });

        });

    });
    </script>

    <!-- Add a <div> element where the tree should appear: -->
    <div id="tree"> </div>

</apex:component>
```

## the output

A tree with all sub nodes open till the last level. I want only first lavel to open. howw to do tat. Is there any setting or something else? please help

Answer (score 1):

Everything is in dynatree [docs](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html) and [examples](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/samples.html). Check `minExpandLevel` http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-minexpand.html

Comment: Hi I added minExpandLevel, but it does not work. it is not showing any js error also in error console of the browser

Comment: Also, in your data items, make sure you have `expand` property set to false. Maybe `minExpandLevel` is not you are looking for, as it will make first level nodes not collapsible.